# how to write Query for result ,sum to columns in different tabele

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I can sum two columns but **tabel A** group by *idprice*

[image]

Comment: Pretty simple aggregation query -- `join` the tables together and use `sum` with `group by`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    a.idprice,
    sum(a.tax) + b.price as sum_price
from 
    tableA a
    inner join 
        tableB b on b.idprice = a.idprice
group by
    a.idprice,
    b.price
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74bdf/2)

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
select t1.tax + t2.price as new_col_name
from
(
    select idprice, sum(tax) as tax
    from table1
    group by idprice
) t1
join table2 t2
on t1.idprice = t2.idprice;
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Select (Sum(A.tax) + Sum(B.Price)) As Result 
From TableA A Inner Join TableB B on A.idprice = B.idprice  
Group By A.idprice
```